# images.xcassets Launchimage sizes for iOS8? Retina HD5.5, Retina HD 4.7 and Retina 4

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcasset

WHat are the LaunchImages Sizes for IOS8?

What is Retina HD5.5, Retina HD 4.7 and Retina 4 ? sizes?

and at what DPI ?? 72 I presume?

A link to apple docs would be great as I cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/PRERELEASE/IOS/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html):

**For iPhone 6:**

750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait

1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape

**For iPhone 6 Plus:**

1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait

2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape

**Retina 4** is the same R4 asset in previous versions of Xcode to support @2x graphics on the 4 inch screen

640 x 1136 for portrait (ex. Default–568h@2x.png)

All images at 72 dpi

Comment: These are not for iOS 8.